# Attribute.IsDefined returns false, Attribute.GetCustomAttribute returns null for defined ActionNameAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to set up some unit tests to ensure that URLs will be mapped to the appropriate controllers and actions according to a route-table, and that the target action-method and controller exists within the relevant assembly.

The only remaining problem I'm having is testing the existence of an action-method where an `ActionNameAttribute` has been applied to enable dash-separated action-name mappings, e.g., a "Contact Us" form url: `/contact-us` maps to the ContactUs method on a Forms controller because the ContactUs method signature is defined thusly:

```
[ActionName("contact-us")]
public ActionResult ContactUs()
```

I've set up the following method, which I am running inside each test, and works for all cases where the action-method name is *not* redefined with `ActionNameAttribute`:

```
private static bool ActionIsDefinedOnController(string expectedActionName, string controllerName, string assemblyName)
{
    var thisControllerType = Type.GetType(AssemblyQualifiedName(controllerName, assemblyName), false, true);

    if (thisControllerType == null)
        return false;

    var allThisControllersActions = thisControllerType.GetMethods().Select(m => m.Name.ToLower());

    if( allThisControllersActions.Contains(expectedActionName.ToLower()))
        return true;

    var methods = thisControllerType.GetMethods();

    //If we've so far failed to find the method, look for methods with ActionName attributes, and check in those values:
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        if (Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(ActionNameAttribute)) 
        {
            var a = (ActionNameAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method, typeof (ActionNameAttribute));
            if (a.Name == expectedActionName)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

...but whenever a method's name is redifined with `ActionNameAttribute`, the check `Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(ActionNameAttribute)` is failing (returns `false`), even when I can see the attribute in the list of custom-attributes in my debugging session:

[image: Failure of Action.IsDefined]

**Why is this check failing, when it should be passing?**

I've been able to construct a different check:

**UPDATE** I had pasted in the wrong code here initially, here's the revised:

```
List<string> customAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(false).Select(a => a.ToString()).ToList();

if (customAttributes.Contains("System.Web.Mvc.ActionNameAttribute")) 
{
    var a = (ActionNameAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method, typeof (ActionNameAttribute));
    if (a.Name == expectedActionName)
        return true;
}
```

...and now my condition is catching the cases where `ActionNameAttribute` is applied, but now `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute()` returns null.    So I can't check the value of the action name to compare against the expected value...  arrrrgh!

Comment: There are multiple `ActionNameAttribute`s in the framework. Are you sure that the one in your `typeof` calls *is* the one in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace? (we can't see your `using` statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just have:

```
//If we've so far failed to find the method, look for methods with ActionName attributes, and check in those values:
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var attr = method.GetCustomAttribute<System.Web.Mvc.ActionNameAttribute>();
    if (attr!=null && attr.Name == expectedActionName)
    {        
       return true;
    }
}
```

As I said in comment, I suspect that you're picking up the *wrong* `ActionNameAttribute` in your `typeof` calls, so I've been explicit

Comment: Note: Your precise code doesn't work for me (`GetCustomAttribute` is .net 4.5, I'm on 4.0), but your point about possibly accessing the wrong `ActionNameAttribute`  tipped me off -- my problem was that I hadn't upgraded the MVC framework reference in the test project since I'd upgraded the target project. All tests had been working anyway (it wasn't so thoroughly covered) until I tried to improve the route tests as I outlined.